# Bring the executor when moving a person from one voice to another Discordjs v14

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a problem, which is that I cannot get the executor that moveing the member from one voice to another, and also if I brought it via fetchAuditLogs, when the user moves between the voices himself, the event will be run and the last executor that moveing the member from one voice to another voice will be fetched.

This is code

1:

```
const { client } = require("../../../index");
import LogsVoiceStateUpdate from "../../eventsServices/Logs/voiceStateUpdate"
module.exports = {
  name: "voiceStateUpdate"
};

client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldUser: any, newUser: any) => {
     LogsVoiceStateUpdate(client, oldUser, newUser)
});
```

2:

```
import { EmbedBuilder, AuditLogEvent } from "discord.js";
import { GetGuildLogsServices } from "../../../api/services/guild/inDashboard/logs";

export = async (client: any, oldUser: any, newUser: any) => {
    try {
        const guildData: any = await GetGuildLogsServices(newUser.guild.id);

        if (guildData) {
            const event = guildData.logs.find((log: any) => log.events.some((event: any) => event.eventName === "voiceStateUpdate"));
            if (!event.enabled) return;

            if (event) {
                const eventName = event.events.find((event: any) => event.eventName === "voiceStateUpdate");

                if (!eventName) return;
                if (!eventName.enabled) return;
                if (!newUser.guild.members.cache.get(client.user.id).permissions.has('EmbedLinks')) return;

                const logChannel = newUser.guild.channels.cache.get(eventName.channelId);
                if (!logChannel) return;

                // Check if the user was moved by someone else
                oldUser.guild.fetchAuditLogs().then((logs: any) => {
                    var userID = logs.entries.first().executor.id;

                    if (oldUser.serverMute === false && newUser.serverMute === true) {
                        let serverMutev = new EmbedBuilder()
                            .setTitle('Voice Mute')
                            .setColor(eventName.color)
                            .addFields(
                                { name: `User:`, value: `<@${oldUser.id}>`, inline: true },
                                { name: `By:`, value: `<@${userID}>`, inline: true },
                                { name: `Channel:`, value: `<#${oldUser.channelId}>`, inline: true },
                            )
                            .setTimestamp()
                            .setFooter({ text: newUser.guild.name, iconURL: newUser.guild.iconURL() })

                        logChannel.send({ embeds: [serverMutev] });
                    }

                    if (oldUser.serverMute === true && newUser.serverMute === false) {

                        let serverUnmutev = new EmbedBuilder()
                            .setTitle('Voice Unmute')
                            .setColor(eventName.color)
                            .addFields(
                                { name: `User:`, value: `<@${oldUser.id}>`, inline: true },
                                { name: `By:`, value: `<@${userID}>`, inline: true },
                                { name: `Channel:`, value: `<#${oldUser.channelId}>`, inline: true },
                            )
                            .setTimestamp()
                            .setFooter({ text: newUser.guild.name, iconURL: newUser.guild.iconURL() })

                        logChannel.send({ embeds: [serverUnmutev] });
                    }

                    if (oldUser.serverDeaf === false && newUser.serverDeaf === true) {

                        let serverDeafv = new EmbedBuilder()
                            .setTitle('Voice Deafen')
                            .setColor(eventName.color)
                            .addFields(
                                { name: `User:`, value: `<@${oldUser.id}>`, inline: true },
                                { name: `By:`, value: `<@${userID}>`, inline: true },
                                { name: `Channel:`, value: `<#${oldUser.channelId}>`, inline: true },
                            )
                            .setTimestamp()
                            .setFooter({ text: newUser.guild.name, iconURL: newUser.guild.iconURL() })

                        logChannel.send({ embeds: [serverDeafv] });
                    }

                    if (oldUser.serverDeaf === true && newUser.serverDeaf === false) {

                        let serverUndeafv = new EmbedBuilder()
                            .setTitle('Voice Undeafen')
                            .setColor(eventName.color)
                            .addFields(
                                { name: `User:`, value: `<@${oldUser.id}>`, inline: true },
                                { name: `By:`, value: `<@${userID}>`, inline: true },
                                { name: `Channel:`, value: `<#${oldUser.channelId}>`, inline: true },
                            )
                            .setTimestamp()
                            .setFooter({ text: newUser.guild.name, iconURL: newUser.guild.iconURL() })

                        logChannel.send({ embeds: [serverUndeafv] });
                    }

                })

                if (oldUser.channelId !== newUser.channelId && newUser.channelId && oldUser.channelId != null) {

                    let voiceLeave = new EmbedBuilder()
                        .setTitle('Voice Switch')
                        .setColor(eventName.color)
                        .addFields(
                            { name: `User:`, value: `<@${oldUser.id}>`, inline: true },
                            { name: `From:`, value: `<#${oldUser.channelId}>`, inline: true },
                            { name: `To:`, value: `<#${newUser.channelId}>`, inline: true },
                        )
                        .setTimestamp()
                        .setFooter({ text: newUser.guild.name, iconURL: newUser.guild.iconURL() })

                    logChannel.send({ embeds: [voiceLeave] });
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Voice State Update Error Log: ${err}`);
    }
};
```

I tried to fetch it via fetchAuditLogs but as I said it didn't work